# Integrating problem with $\sin x$

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate the following definite integral:

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x}\,dx\end{align}$$

My try:

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x}\,dx=\\\left(-\cos \pi\right)-\left(-\cos 0\right)=\\-1-(-1)=\\0\end{align}$$

But the actual result (by wolframalpha) is: **2**

I'm sure that there is something I miss.

> **Sorry the problem was with my calculator (I forget to convert my system from Deg to Rad)**

Comment: $\cos \pi=1$, are you sure?

Comment: Negative cosine of pi is what?

Comment: @abiessu -0.9984

Comment: @MohammadFakhrey That is $-\cos \pi^\circ$

Comment: Please delete this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You incorrectly calculated $-\cos\pi$:

$$-\cos\pi = -(-1) = 1.$$